# Convert varchar string into Date format Query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

I'm having a trouble on how can I convert my filename into date time format. The format of my filename is varchar and The problem is the last part  of the name file is not formatted as a date it should be formatted in `hour`, `minutes` and `AM/PM` see my sample image below. do you have any idea of this ? change from 33250400 to 01-47 PM. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

> Expected output

```
2021-03-30-01-47 PM.csv
```

[sample-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5E1w.png)

*What I've tried*

```
 ->select(['table.*',DB::raw(' DATE_FORMAT(table.file_name, "%Y-%m-%d-%h:%i %p") AS final_date')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing filename to DATE_FORMAT function which contains .csv extension that is why you are not getting your expected output but if you still want date time format of filename then you can select records from database and you can remove .csv extension from each filename record string and then use date function to get your desired output

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've been mistaken from my question. I just want to get the value to those I've been marked red in the image into hour and minutes and then the format of the file like `.csv`

Comment: The output should look like this `2021-03-30-01-47 PM.csv` do you have idea of this ? from `33250400` to  `01-47 PM.`